# Substituir NA por dado de outra coluna

Tags: r

Gostaria de substituir `NA` pelo conteúdo de outra coluna. Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
NOME    TIPO        VALOR
ABC     INTERNACAO  10
ADD                 20
AFF     CONSULTA    30
DDD     EXAME       40
RTF                 50
DRGG    EXAME       60
```

Como faria para substituir o `NA` pelo conteúdo da coluna ao lado? Exemplo: O `NA` da linha `ADD` (coluna `TIPO`), seria substituído pelo número 20.  E na linha `RTF` (coluna `TIPO`) seria substituído por 50. Grato

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao criar o seu exemplo, a variável `TIPO` vem como `factor`. Tive que transformá-la em `character` para atribuir um número na posição vazia.

```
dados <- data.frame(NOME = c("ABC", "ADD", "AFF", "DDD", "RTF", "DRGG"),
                TIPO = c("INTERNACAO", "", "CONSULTA", "EXAME", "", "EXAME"),
                VALOR = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60))
dados$TIPO <- as.character(dados$TIPO)
pos <- which(dados$TIPO == "")
dados$TIPO[pos] <- dados$VALOR[pos]
```

Comment: o exemplo que você utilizou está como vazio. Como faria se os dados estivessem com NA?

Comment: substitua a linha com o comando `which` por `pos <- which(is.na(dados$TIPO))`